# JavaFX 8 update UI with Platfrom.runLater() still returns null

Tags: java, javafx-8

I'm currently writing an HexEditor Application with JavaFX 8 for various reasons. (Important is, that I have to do this I can't just use another HexEditor)

My problem is that when I want to update my UI for example with

```
textarea.setText(line);
table.setItems(getListForTable());
```

I get a NullPointerException because `textarea`(TextArea) and `table` (TableView) are null, but if I have data before I intialize my stage and set that to the components it works.

In other questions I read that `Platfrom.runLater()` should solve that but somehow it doesn`t work for me, I still get the NullPointerException. Also I'm sure I'm in the applications main thread, because my application only uses one thread.

Here is the full code from the method:

```
public void openFile() //this is called when the user presses the "Open"-MenuItem
{       
    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
    fc.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
             new ExtensionFilter("Text Files", "*.txt"),
             new ExtensionFilter("All Files", "*.*"));
    file = fc.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
  if(file != null)
  {
    create();
    Platform.runLater(() -> textarea.setText(line)); //NPE
  }
}
```

Also I tried using a button to update the UI but that works only if the user presses the button and also not with the `Button.fire()` Method, but thats not a good workaround if you have to press that button everytime you did something to see the changes.

EDIT: here are the methods initializing the code in the `start()` Method. And as I said: I`m sure there getting assigned correctly, because I can use them for setting up listeners and such while starting the program.

```
private TextArea textarea;
private TableView<Row> table; //Row is my own class used to get the contents to the table

    public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    initRootLayout();
    showContentScene();
}

private void initRootLayout() {  //initializes root layout as frame for Content
    try {
        // Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Editor.class.getResource("RootLayout.fxml"));
        rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void showContentScene() {  //initializes Content View
    try {
        // Load Content (panel).
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Editor.class.getResource("Content.fxml"));
        ContentPane = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        table = (TableView<Row>) loader.getNamespace().get("table");
        textarea = (TextArea) loader.getNamespace().get("textarea");

        // Set Content into the center of root layout.
        rootLayout.setCenter(ContentPane);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

EDIT: I overworked the code structure but now I have another exception from the loader telling me "Root cannot be null".

EDIT: For everyone viewing this: It was mostly a structure problem, make sure that every .fxml-file you use has its own Controller.

Comment: `runLater` won't solve anything because you have no idea when it will be executed. Where are your components initialized is the only relevant question

Comment: The components are initialized in the `start()` Method from `Application`

Comment: Can you include this code ? You should never ask a question about an `NPE` without providing at least the line causing the error, the way this line is  called, and the initialization code

Comment: I have edited the question including the code.

Comment: Who calls `showContentScene` ? Where is `start` ? By the way by the look of these methods they should be private

Comment: This is all from one class, also you're right, I changed the methods to private .

Comment: I see, unfortunately I have never used an `FXMLLoader` so I'm not sure why it returns `null` values. Did you try printing `loader.getNamespace()` ?

Comment: Yeah, as I wrote above the values get assigned correctly it's just null if I want to use it aftere the initializing is done. Also a user activated Button works but not one fired from the code.

Comment: Hmmm a non-null variable cannot become null unless it is reassigned. Make sure they are never reassigned and add a nullity check in `showContentScene` (something like `if (blabla == null) throw new RuntimeException("Could not initialize blabla")`

Comment: If I understood it correctly the JavaFX main Thread is reassigning the variables during runtime, thats why I tried to use `Platform.runlater()` to get the variables while they are assigned.

Comment: I would be pissed if a framework arbitrarily overwrote the values I put in my variables... that cannot be true. Just add nullity checks and make sure they are never reassigned by your code

Comment: You will generally get better help sooner using by including an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question, that way somebody could just copy and paste your (minimal) code and run it without modification to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is very unusual.  Usually you either construct nodes in your code and don't use and FXMLLoader OR you let the FXMLLoader construct nodes for you.  In your case you are doing both, which can work, but is tricky to get right (as you have discovered).

So, given you are using FXML, just use it for constructing all of your nodes and place references to the constructed nodes in a controller, with the references annotated with @FXML so that the FXMLLoader initializes them.  Then, never assign the references to new nodes you create.

Ensure that the references and controller are in different classes from your Application class, because you never really want to make the main application class a controller, all the main application class should do is invoke the FXMLLoader, it does not need any node references.

You never need to use Platform.runLater unless you are running on a non-JavaFX application thread and you want to execute some code on the JavaFX application thread.  For your example this is clearly not the case, because the comment for openFile is `this is called when the user presses the "Open"-MenuItem`.  The JavaFX framework handles the input event for the user pressing the open menu item and ensures that an event handler for it is invoked on the JavaFX application thread, so trying to use Platform.runLater in such a situation is both confusing and redundant.

Even if you address some of the issues mentioned in this answer, your program may still not work as you expect as it may have other issues, which cannot be verified with the current code in your question.  For instance, the question code includes neither FXML or controller code.  Those would be required to truly find all the issues with code and address this.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I tried to correct my structure with this tutorial: http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part1/, but now I have another Exception "Root cannot be null". The thing is that I have a root element, but the loader somehow won't recognise it. (So now I need help to fix that, before I can get back to my old problem) MCVE is also now included in the question.

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you include the code for the MCVE in your question rather than as an off-site archive.  If you have created minimal code that replicates only the issue you have, then there won't be too much code.

Comment: When you get enough reputation, please [post a self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that others who encounter your issue could benefit from your solution.